# python int doesn't have __iadd__() method?

Tags: python, integer, immutability

I know this is bad practice:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> a.__radd__(5)
10
>>> a
5
>>> a.__iadd__(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__iadd__'
```

Out of curiosity, if an int object doesn't have `__iadd__`, then how does `+=` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Out of curiosity, if an int object doesn't have `__iadd__`, then how does += work?

```
a += 5
```

Becomes

```
a = a + 5
```

Because there's no `__iadd__` for immutable objects.

This is (in effect)

```
a = a.__add__( 5 )
```

And works nicely.  A new int object is created by `__add__`.

Some of the rules are here http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules.

Comment: Which is of course because integers are immutable, i.e. there's no way an integer object can increment itself.

Comment: `a += 5` does not become `a = a + 5`. It can call `__add__`, but only if `__iadd__` doesn't exist (as Paulo Scardino mentions.)

Comment: @Thomas Wouters: It may not always be transformed into that, but it does for the case the OP asked about, namely "if an `int` object doesn't have `__iadd__`, then how does `+=` work?" -- as it would with other immutable types that have an `__add__` method.

Answer (score 3):

If an object does not have `__iadd__`, `__add__` will be used. Method `__iadd__` is suposed to be an optimized inplace `__add__` case, it is not mandatory.